# How Update Maximage at the end or start the cycle of the images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, maximage2

I'm using the jquery Maximage add-on to create a full-screen slideshow, loading the images dynamically with php, json and mysql.
The problem is that if I upload one or more new images in the database, Maximage does not update the new images automatically.
Any idea how I can do to update Maximage at the end or start the cycle of the images?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class='no-js' lang='en'>
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />        
    <title>Kiosco</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/css/jquery.maximage.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/css/screen.css">
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">          
        #maximage {
        /* position:fixed !important; */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="maximage">
        <?php
            include "conexion/conexion.php";
            // Consult the database
            $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT name FROM files ORDER BY position ASC");
            //Load images
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        ?>
                    <img src="/KioskoImage/lib/images/ImagesDisplay/<?php echo $row['name'];?>" alt="" width="1400" height="1050">
        <?php 
            }
            //Close BD
            mysqli_close($con);
        ?>
    </div>
    <script src="lib/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/js/jquery.cycle.all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="lib/js/jquery.maximage.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            // Trigger maximage
            jQuery('#maximage').maximage();
        });
    </script>     
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#maximage').maximage({
            onImagesLoaded:      function() { 
                location.reload();
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please consider adding relevant code to your question for specific/helpful answer

Comment: this creates a loop that updates the page in the first image indefinitely
onImagesLoaded:      function() { 
    location.reload();
}